# Can't play video VideoView android error on phone and emulator

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Getting following error:
 Cant play video VideoView android error on phone and emulator. 
when used youtub url, local hard disk path. Don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the code that is causing the problem?